# How can i select some id with xx-xxx-xx-x format?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio

I need to change below data

```
A320-ZL-522-01-1(2)
A320-ZL-531-01-1(1)
A320-ZL-531-01-1(2)
A320-ZL-531-01-1(1)
A320-ZL-531-01-1(2)
```

to

```
ZL-522-01-1
ZL-531-01-1
ZL-531-01-1
ZL-531-01-1
ZL-531-01-1
```

Can I do it with LINQ using RegEx?

```
public class MatchCTallyToCross
{
    public List<string> Get(string CustomerNumber)
    {
        IEngManager engManager = new EngManager();
        EngCustomerMyCross engCustomerMyCross = new EngCustomerMyCross();
        engManager.Load(engCustomerMyCross);
        return engCustomerMyCross.myEngCustomerCross.
            Where(c => c.ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_CUSTOMER_NUMBER == CustomerNumber).
            Select(c => c.ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO).ToList();
    }
}
```

```
c => c.ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO result is equal to "A320-ZL-531-01-1(2)"
```

But i need `"ZL-531-01-1"`.

Comment: You have asked **236 questions**. I think that's enough to know how to properly format them. Please have a look at the [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and at my edits on your question. This might actually save you a lot of time in future.

Comment: maybe you could also bother accepting and voting some more answers...

Comment: i think that stackoverflow not good i try to write code my codes look bad. Some editors has got: [code][/code]  i think that it is good!!!

Comment: No, that's not good. You had to replace all your `<` and `>`. Just past your code, then select the block and press `Ctrl+K` or use the `Code Sample` button. Your code is indented by four spaces, which is the Markdown way of telling that it's code. Please have a look at your edited question.

Comment: If you don't think StackOverflow is good, why do you post here?!

Why are so many people behaving as if places like SO are people who's job is to help them. It is not, we are all developers spending their free time here because it is thrilling to answer questions, not because we have to or get paid. (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use an [extension Method](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/13/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods.aspx) inside linq to reformat your string using regex.

```
c.ENG_CUSTOMERMYCROSS_MYTECHNIC_TASK_NO.ToNewDateFormat()//calling the extension method
```